# Find rejected call state code in Android

Tags: android

For rejected call in Android what will be the state code from Call logger.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html

for INCOMING 1, MISSED 3, OUTGOING 2 are the states,

```
` String[] projection = new String[] {
                    CallLog.Calls._ID,
                    CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                    CallLog.Calls.DATE,
                    CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                    CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                    CallLog.Calls.NEW,
                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL,
                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_TYPE
            };
            Cursor c =  mct.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
```

When i query like this what will be the TYPE for rejected calls?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, rejected call is not repertoried in CallLog.Calls.

I found that 6 is used by android for rejected call.

Comment: You could comment this instead.

Comment: Hi, sorry for delay in reply. actually Android documentation nowhere officially says REJECT call state. For my S duos handset with ICS the rejected state is shown as 5. But for MOTO G with Kitkat the rejected state is showing as incoming call.

Comment: Did you try any workaround, i have a very crude work around, if its incoming call & call duration is 0, then its rejected call. If the call state is 3, then its missed call. `Note: 3 is missed call officially stated by android`

Comment: Hi, I have an application that use this constants. And it work fine.


    public final static int INCOMING_TYPE = CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE;
    public final static int OUTGOING_TYPE = CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE;
    public final static int MISSED_TYPE = CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE;
    public final static int REJECTED_TYPE = 5;
    public final static int REJECTED_LIST_TYPE = 6;